# What does it mean when the stopping condition of a for loop is a lone pointer variable?

Tags: c++, syntax, for-loop

I encountered a for loop where the condition is the parameter (p) itself. When will the loop stop? I don't see this case in my C++ books.

```
for (PDFS *p = e->prev ; p ; p = p->prev) {
    push_back (p->edge);
    edge[p->edge->id] = vertex[p->edge->from] = vertex[p->edge->to] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edition by @Rob Kennedy

Comment: Can you help me by solving this question? Thanks:) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780955/unexpected-result-of-my-dfs-tree-c
  @Rob Kennedy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loop will stop when `p` is `NULL`. In the loop, you don't need to explicitly check  for the condition `p !=NULL`, or in C++11, `p != nullptr`.

The similar code is also written you've null-terminated c-string:

```
 char str[] = "its null-terminated string";
 for(size_t i = 0 ; str[i] ;  ++i)
        std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;
```

In this case, you don't need to check for the condition `i < strlen(str)`  or something like that.

Comment: Although this is the right answer, I'd say when `p == nullptr`.

Comment: @daknok_t, `nullptr` is a C++11 keyword.

Comment: @Nawaz Can you help me by solving this question? Thanks:)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780955/unexpected-result-of-my-dfs-tree-c

Answer (score 2):

It will stop when `p` is `NULL` or `0`.

This will happen when `p->prev` does not point to another element.

Answer (score 1):

It will stop when p pointer will equal to NULL pointer