# Unexpected result of my DFS tree (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

**I have solved this problem!!! I found that if i have to use `vector<Node*> children;`. But I am not very sure the reason, can someone tell me why? Thanks:)**

**Question:**

I use `test.cpp` to generate a tree structure like:

[image]

The result of `(ROOT->children).size()` is `2`, since `root` has two children.

The result of `((ROOT->children)[0].children).size()` should be `2`, since the first child of `root` has two children. But the answer is `0`, why? It really confuse for me.

> test.cpp (This code is runnable in visual studio 2010)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int len;
    vector<Node> children;
    Node *prev;
    Node(): len(0), children(0), prev(0) {};
};

class gSpan {
public:
    Node *ROOT;
    Node *PREV;
    void read();
    void insert(int);
};

int main() {
    gSpan g;
    g.read();
    system("pause");
}

void gSpan::read() {
    int value[4] = {1, 2, 2, 1};
    ROOT = new Node();
    PREV = ROOT;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        insert(value[i]);
    }
    cout << "size1: " << (ROOT->children).size() << endl; // it should output 2
    cout << "size2: " << ((ROOT->children)[0].children).size() << endl; // it should output 2
    system("pause");
}

void gSpan::insert(int v) {

    while(v <= PREV->len)
        PREV = PREV->prev;
    Node *cur = new Node();
    cur->len = v;
    cur->prev = PREV;
    PREV->children.push_back(*cur);
    PREV = cur;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you `children` vector contains `Node` values rather than `Node*` pointers. While your access uses the root correctly, it finds only copies of the children you try to maintain. All of your nodes are also leaked.

You might want to use a `std::vector<Node*>` for your children and `delete` them at some point. The easiest way is probably to use a vector of smart pointers, e.g. a teference counted pointer, and have the smart pointer take care of the release.

Comment: I don't understand this statement means: `it finds only copies of the children you try to maintain. All of your nodes are also leaked.`. If i use `vector<Node> children`, the `Node` object should be in children if i push_back it. But why it is disappear? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You don't put the `Node` there to which you point but a copy thereof. In C++ objects are valuesm, not pointers. If you draw a rectangle for every `Node` object and an arrow for every `Node*` to the corresponding `Node` you may see the problem: when you `push_back()` your `*cur` you put a new `Node` (i.e. a rectangle) into the `children` vector but you have mo arrow to it. When you add a child later you change it via the arrow but when you try to look at the size you go via the array.